# SQL Union on the Join subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I've got a specific requirement where the backend is supposed to send records that match on a certain criteria from a table. There is a version table that basically contains
[id, ..., modstamp, deleted]
The requirement is to get the records that match between timestamp t1 and t2.
I think I could explain with respect to the sql script:

```
create table test (id varchar(10), cv_modstamp DATETIMEOFFSET, sf_deleteddate DATETIMEOFFSET);
insert into test values ('aaa', '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00', null);
insert into test values ('bbb', '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00', NULL);
insert into test values ('eee', '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00', NULL);
insert into test values ('aaa', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00', NULL);
insert into test values ('bbb', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00');
insert into test values ('ccc', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00', NULL);
insert into test values ('ddd', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00', '2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00');
select * from test;


select D1.*, D2.* from
(
select A.* 
FROM TEST A, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                  FROM TEST
                  WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
                  GROUP BY id) T
WHERE A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
 AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
 AND   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
) D1
INNER JOIN
 (
    select A.* 
    FROM TEST A, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                  FROM TEST
                  WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
                  GROUP BY id) T
    WHERE A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
    AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
    AND   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
 )
D2 ON D1.ID = D2.ID
```

This gives out the response:

```
aaa 2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00      aaa 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00  
eee 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00      eee 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00
```

But what is required is:

```
aaa 2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00      
aaa 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00  
eee 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00  
eee 2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00
```

Is there a way to display the joined sets on union?

Edit:
Thanks all for the solutions. Each one is good enough for SQL Server. I wanted this to be achieved in a single query. Might be porting similar queries to other database flavors too.

Edit2:
What if the entire columnset have to be selected?

This can be achieved with CTE queries

```
with subset1 as 
(
    select A.* FROM TEST A,
    (
        SELECT
            id AS T_ALIAS_ID,
            MAX( CV_Modstamp ) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
        FROM
            TEST
        WHERE
            CV_Modstamp <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
        GROUP BY
            id
    ) T
    WHERE
        A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
        AND A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
        AND A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
)
, subset2 as 
(
    select A.* FROM TEST A,
    (
        SELECT
            id AS T_ALIAS_ID,
            MAX( CV_Modstamp ) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
        FROM
            TEST
        WHERE
            CV_Modstamp > '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
            AND CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
        GROUP BY
            id
    ) T
    WHERE
        A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
        AND A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
        AND A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
)

select subset1.* from subset1, subset2 where subset1.id = subset2.id
union all 
select subset2.* from subset1, subset2 where subset1.id = subset2.id
order by id, cv_modstamp;
```

Comment: Why do you want `eee` to be duplicated?

Comment: Here's one possibility: http://rextester.com/BUJY49274

Comment: @gh9 Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the first set where clause to
`WHERE CV_Modstamp > '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00' AND CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'`

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple way to do it using your existing code and just wrapping it in a CTE. I've used a table variable so I can run it as a prototype locally without the drop statement, otherwise the code is all yours except the CTE wrapper.

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE
  (
       [id]               VARCHAR(10)
       , [cv_modstamp]    DATETIMEOFFSET
       , [sf_deleteddate] DATETIMEOFFSET
  );

INSERT INTO @test
VALUES      ('aaa','2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00',NULL),
            ('bbb','2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00',NULL),
            ('eee','2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00',NULL),
            ('aaa','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00',NULL),
            ('bbb','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00'),
            ('ccc','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00',NULL),
            ('ddd','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00','2017-10-28 22:45:44 +00:00');

SELECT *
FROM   @test;

WITH [builder]
     AS (SELECT [D1].[id]            AS [d1_id]
                , [D1].[cv_modstamp] AS [d1_cv_modstamp]
                , [D2].[id]          AS [d2_id]
                , [D2].[cv_modstamp] AS [d2_cv_modstamp]
         FROM   (SELECT [A].*
                 FROM   @test [A]
                        , (SELECT [id]                 AS [T_ALIAS_ID]
                                  , MAX([CV_Modstamp]) AS [T_ALIAS_lastModTime]
                           FROM   @test
                           WHERE  [CV_Modstamp] <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
                           GROUP  BY [id]) [T]
                 WHERE  [A].[id] = [T].[T_ALIAS_ID]
                        AND [A].[CV_Modstamp] = [T].[T_ALIAS_lastModTime]
                        AND [A].[SF_Deleteddate] IS NULL) [D1]
                INNER JOIN (SELECT [A].*
                            FROM   @test [A]
                                   , (SELECT [id]                 AS [T_ALIAS_ID]
                                             , MAX([CV_Modstamp]) AS [T_ALIAS_lastModTime]
                                      FROM   @test
                                      WHERE  [CV_Modstamp] <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
                                      GROUP  BY [id]) [T]
                            WHERE  [A].[id] = [T].[T_ALIAS_ID]
                                   AND [A].[CV_Modstamp] = [T].[T_ALIAS_lastModTime]
                                   AND [A].[SF_Deleteddate] IS NULL) [D2]
                        ON [D1].[ID] = [D2].[ID]) SELECT [d1_id]
       , [d1_cv_modstamp]
FROM   [builder]
UNION ALL
SELECT [d2_id]
       , [d2_cv_modstamp]
FROM   [builder];
```

Comment: To generalize the selection of entire rows, (select *), can this be done without running another join on the same table?

Answer (score 1):

To force output of one source row to 2 output rows you can just use a tiny `cross join` and a `case expression`:

```
select 
       case when cj.n = 1 then d1.id          else d2.id end as id
     , case when cj.n = 1 then d1.CV_Modstamp else d2.CV_Modstamp end as CV_Modstamp
from (
     select A.* 
     FROM TEST A
     INNER JOIN (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                       FROM TEST
                       WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
                       GROUP BY id) T
             ON A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID  AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
     WHERE  A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
     ) D1
INNER JOIN (
    select A.* 
    FROM TEST A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                  FROM TEST
                  WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
                  GROUP BY id) T
                ON A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
    WHERE   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
    ) D2 ON D1.ID = D2.ID
CROSS JOIN (select 1 n union all select 2) cj
```

*dbfiddle [demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=11afba0d5a6311f6ea68a2c27515d7ab)*

Comment: Can select be generalized to all the columns here,i.e. Like d1.* or d2.*?

Comment: No. You cannot use an asterix here. In any case you should not use an asterix in any production query.

Answer (score 1):

I reused your query and stored it in a table `temp1` using which UNION ALL was done.

```
select * into temp1 from (
select D1.*, D2.* from
(
select A.id as A_id, A.cv_modstamp as A_cv_modstamp,  A.sf_deleteddate as A_sf_deleteddate
FROM TEST A, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                  FROM TEST
                  WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
                  GROUP BY id) T
WHERE A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
 AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
 AND   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
) D1
INNER JOIN
 (
    select B.id as B_id, B.cv_modstamp as B_cv_modstamp,  B.sf_deleteddate as B_sf_deleteddate
    FROM TEST B, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                  FROM TEST
                  WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
                  GROUP BY id) T
    WHERE B.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
    AND   B.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
    AND   B.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
 )
D2 ON D1.A_ID = D2.B_ID ) as tt;

select * from temp1;


select A_id, A_cv_modstamp from temp1
UNION ALL
select B_id, B_cv_modstamp from temp1
order by A_id;
```

Comment: That's one possibility and requires some cleanup with multiple queries. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Please use this:

```
select 
     id = col.value('(id)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)')
    ,cv_modstamp = col.value('(cv_modstamp)[1]', 'datetimeoffset(7)')
    ,sf_deleteddate = col.value('(sf_deleteddate)[1]', 'datetimeoffset(7)')
from

( select [myData] = convert(xml, (

    select 
         [rec/id] = D1.id, [rec/cv_modstamp] = d1.cv_modstamp, [rec/sf_deleteddate] = d1.sf_deleteddate
        ,[data] = null
        ,[rec/id] = D2.id, [rec/cv_modstamp] = d2.cv_modstamp, [rec/sf_deleteddate] = d2.sf_deleteddate
    from
    (
    select A.* 
    FROM TEST A, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                      FROM TEST
                      WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-11-14 18:45:44 +00:00'
                      GROUP BY id) T
    WHERE A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
     AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
     AND   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
    ) D1
    INNER JOIN
     (
        select A.* 
        FROM TEST A, (SELECT id AS T_ALIAS_ID, MAX(CV_Modstamp) AS T_ALIAS_lastModTime
                      FROM TEST
                      WHERE CV_Modstamp <= '2017-10-27 18:45:44 +00:00'
                      GROUP BY id) T
        WHERE A.id = T.T_ALIAS_ID
        AND   A.CV_Modstamp = T.T_ALIAS_lastModTime
        AND   A.SF_Deleteddate IS NULL
     )
    D2 ON D1.ID = D2.ID
    FOR XML PATH('data')
))) as t
cross apply t.myData.nodes('data/rec') as tab(col);
```